# Why NativeJ 32bit .exe file generated from .jar doesn't work?

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to create .exe files using NativeJ from a .jar taking from my Netbeans project. NativeJ allows to create 2 versions of .exe files: 32bit and 64bit. I tried to create both (my architecture is 64bit ones). The .exe 64bit version works fine but the 32bit (runned on 32bit architecture PC) display this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pack/ApplicationForm
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.ApplicationForm
```

Why there's this exception only with 32bit version of .exe file? Any solution?

Comment: Check that generated jar contains `pack/ApplicationForm`

Comment: Why this class is missing only for 32bit .exe file? The 64bit one works fine.

Comment: Inside the .jar file I can see ApplicationForm.class, in fact the 64bit version works.